# displaying data from the database using datagrid , flash , php , mysql , as3

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, datagrid

I got the blank fields of the datagrid which does not display any data , when I try the .`php` or .`xml` file in the browser it displays the whole xml file.

```
    billRecords.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dbShow);

function dbShow(e: MouseEvent): void {
        data_grid.addColumn("Table No");
        data_grid.addColumn("Date");
        data_grid.addColumn("Items");
        data_grid.addColumn("Quantity");
        data_grid.addColumn("Total");
        data_grid.width = 1150;
        data_grid.rowCount = 100;
        data_grid.move(5, 35);
        addChild(data_grid);

        var urlPhp: String = "billrecords.xml";
        var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlPhp);
        var url_loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        url_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        url_loader.load(request);

        close_btn.x = 1155;
        close_btn.y = 10;
        addChild(close_btn);
        close_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, closeDbShow);

    }
    function completeHandler(event: Event): void {
        var ldr: URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;

        // create XML datastructure from loaded XML
        var xmlDP: XML = new XML(ldr.data);
        var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
        xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
        xmlDoc.parseXML(xmlDP.toXMLString());


        var dp=new DataProvider(xmlDP);
       trace(dp);

        data_grid.dataProvider = dp ;

    }
```

When I trace dp it show objects . How can I get these object to show the text in the datagrid . Please guys need help. Does DataGrid Works in Adobe Air apps ?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xmlObject itself. You have only to cast it as `XML` before passing it to the `DataProvider` constructor » `data_grid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(XML(ldr.data))`
Greetings André

Comment: still not getting the text in the data grids.. When I trace ldr.data I get these<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <fields>
    <table>0</table>
    <date>27/4/2015</date>
    <items>ice gola , kulfhi , bhel</items>
    <quantity>2 , 1 , 2</quantity>
    <total>500</total>
  </fields>
  <fields>
    <table>2</table>
    <date>27/4/2015</date>
    <items>gola , bhel , kulfhi</items>
    <quantity>1 , 1 , 1</quantity>
    <total>300</total>
  </fields>
</data>
and When I trace data_grid.dataprovider  I get these
DataProvider [[object Object] , [object Object]]

Answer (score 0):

OK. Actionscript and xml are case-intensive languages.
The datagrid can not find e.g. "**T**able" in the xml, because the xml-node is named "**t**able".

This should solve the problem:

```
dg.addColumn("table");
dg.addColumn("date");
dg.addColumn("items");
dg.addColumn("quantity");
dg.addColumn("total");
dg.getColumnAt(0).headerText="Table";
dg.getColumnAt(1).headerText="Date";
dg.getColumnAt(2).headerText="Items";
dg.getColumnAt(3).headerText="Quantity";
dg.getColumnAt(4).headerText="Total";
```

And the loaderCompleteHandler:

```
function completeHandler(event: Event): void {
    var ldr:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
    var xmlDP:XML = new XML(ldr.data);
    var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider(xmlDP);       
    data_grid.dataProvider = dp ;
}
```

Greetings André